# How do I having one model listen for updates of another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two models, `Subscription` and `Offer`. Subscriptions have many offers. Offers have one subscription.

Subscriptions and offers also have statuses. If the subscription status changes, all associated offers must change with it (but not vice versa).

Right now we're using an after_save hook to go through and update a subscriptions offers. But it seems like too tight of coupling.

I don't know if this is the best solution, but I imagined something like:

1. Subscription saves
2. Subscription broadcasts its `id` and new `status`
3. Offer listens for subscriptions being saved, and updates itself accordingly

Is this a good solution? I haven't really had to break up tight coupling before. I've read about Observers but I don't think it's exactly what I'm looking for, as they're more for observing events of their own models. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wisper](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper) gem is exactly what are you looking for.